# How to make divs stretch horizontally across the page using pixels and not percentage?

Tags: html, css

Basically I don't want to use percentage because pixels are much easier to work with as I know the exact dimensions for stuff therefore I want to make the page width 1024 pixels wide but with it stretching to fit any(most) common resolutions

Comment: width:100%;max-width:1024px; but for responsive design it will not good unless you use percentage. PS: using px it's not easier than using percentage as percentage (if properly coded) are way better. Have a look at this as well for another way to do that: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Do you want 1024px or less?

Comment: No unless it's necessary to achieve what I want.

Comment: Watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBZYJ7QbN_c you will really want to use some kind of percentages otherwise your site will look old and clunky

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnzevjza/ here's what I'm using at moment

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use @media

```
   @media only screen and (min-device-width: 800px) and (max-device-width: 1023px)  {
            #myDiv{width: 800px;}
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1279px)  {
            #myDiv{width: 1024px;}
    }
```

In old browsers use fixed size or make some js tricks.